# Can you offset React Native ScrollView sticky headers?

Tags: react-native, react-native-scrollview

Is it possible to have React Native `ScrollView`'s "sticky headers" (set with `stickyHeaderIndices`) stick somewhere other than the very top of the `ScrollView`.

In my case, I have a 80px partially transparent header over the top of the `ScrollView` and I want the sticky headers to stick at the base of that header. So I need the sticking point to be 80px from the top of the `ScrollView`.